# Hibernate - Set an ManyToOne column value just with id, without an instance of object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have those tables:

```
Name: product
Rows: id

Name: order_product
Rows: id, product_id
```

In java are mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<OrderProduct> orderProductList = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    //...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_product")
public class OrderProduct{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    //...

}
```

When I want to create a new OrderProduct I do this:

```
//existing info
productId = 1;

//get from db product which have id 1
Product product = session.createQuery("FROM Product WHERE id = :pId", Product.class)
                          .setParameter("pId", productId)
                          .getSingleResult();

//create order product
OrderProduct newOrderProduct = new OrderProduct();
newOrderProduct.setProduct(product);

//put in db
session.save(newOrderProduct);
```

What I want is to remove that part where I need to bring the product from db.

I want to `setProduct` of `newOrderProduct` using directly the id.

```
newOrderProduct.setProduct(productId);
```

I know I can done that by eliminate `ManyToOne` and declare variable product as `Integer`. But I don't want to lose the benefit of `ManyToOne`.

There is a way to set the product only by id without having an instance of `Product`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

```java
public boolean createOrderProduct(int productId) {
    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((OrderProduct op) -> {
        INSERT().INTO(op);
        VALUES(row(productId));
    });
    return query.createQuery(em).executeUpdate() > 0;
}
```

produced SQL:

```
INSERT   INTO order_product t0 
VALUES (?1)
```

Detailed [INSERT](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/INSERT) explanation.